# Sum values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to display the total amount of installs each campaign number has had since the beginning using this array.

```
    Array
(
    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-09
                    [hour] => 7
                    [campaign] => 27
                    [installs] => 2
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-09
                    [hour] => 3
                    [campaign] => 39
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-09
                    [hour] => 5
                    [campaign] => 39
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-09
                    [hour] => 6
                    [campaign] => 39
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-09
                    [hour] => 8
                    [campaign] => 39
                    [installs] => 2
                    [trials] => 0
                )
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-10
                    [hour] => 3
                    [campaign] => 53
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-10
                    [hour] => 9
                    [campaign] => 53
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-10
                    [hour] => 5
                    [campaign] => 55
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-10
                    [hour] => 12
                    [campaign] => 55
                    [installs] => 1
                    [trials] => 0
                )

        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-15
                    [hour] => 0
                    [campaign] => 61
                    [installs] => 27
                    [trials] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-15
                    [hour] => 1
                    [campaign] => 61
                    [installs] => 18
                    [trials] => 0
                )
                [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2018-04-15
                    [hour] => 1
                    [campaign] => 27
                    [installs] => 10
                    [trials] => 0
                )
```

My array is shown above. You can see some of the campaign numbers are repeated on different dates. My result should look like:

Campaign 27: 12
Campaign 39: 5
Campaign 53: 2
Campaign 55: 2
Campaign 61: 45

So far I've got this, which doesn't seem to be printing all of the data.

```
    $newarray = array();
$last = count($res) - 1;
foreach ($res as $i => $new){
foreach ($new as $x => $row){
    $isFirst = ($i == 0);
    $isLast = ($i == $last);
    $grabbedvalue = $row['campaign'].",".$row['installs'];
        array_push($newarray,$grabbedvalue);

}
}

print_r($newarray);
```

Hope that someone can help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So where's your attempt?  I'm sure someone is willing to _help_, but not just do it for you.

Comment: just added what I have so far @Mehdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the array and count:

```
$data = [

    [
        'campaign' => 1,
        'installs' => 20, 
    ],
    [
        'campaign' => 1,
        'installs' => 5, 
    ],
    [
        'campaign' => 2,
        'installs' => 1, 
    ],
    [
        'campaign' => 2,
        'installs' => 10, 
    ],
    [
        'campaign' => 3,
        'installs' => 9, 
    ],

];

$count=array();
// Loop through the campaigns
foreach($data as $camp){
    // Check if we initiated the counting before
    if(isset($count[$camp['campaign']])){
        // Add installs count to previous value
        $count[$camp['campaign']] += $camp['installs'];
    } else {
        // Initiate the counting
        $count[$camp['campaign']] = $camp['installs'];
    }
}

var_dump($count);
```

This will give:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => int 25
  2 => int 11
  3 => int 9
```

Comment: @Joas why you think so.

Comment: He did not try to do this himself before asking this question here. When I tried to explain how he could sovle the problem it was clear he did not understand the basics of arrays. I fear he'll just copy the code and use it without looking at it a second time to try to understand what it does.

Comment: @Joas I asked him to post his efforts (see the comments), he did and I saw that it is appropriate to post an answer. The code is comment so he should be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer is correct and the example you specified is well documented, though I fear OP will not look at the documentation and just copy your code. I personally dislike that idea, so I would prefer linking a website where OP can learn about arrays and learn how to do this himself as he appears to fail to understand them. I guess that is just my personal opinion tho.

Comment: @Joas I get your idea, but IMO people can learn by examining code. Linking to off-site resources is discouraged if the content is not in the answer. But anyway, both the answers (yours and mine) are available to whoever reads them.

Comment: @James I know that a lot of people (especially new members) just expect us to be coding for them. "_where do you draw the line_" I don't actually have a rule but, if I see that the OP tried some code (not just random non-sense code) and he is in the way of getting the answer, I post the solution with comments and documentation links if needed. But I actually think in this case unfortunately I'm wrong the OP did not reply to my answer nor the other one.

Comment: @Mehdi Hey Mehdi, I am thankful for your answer, it didn't initially provide me with the result I was looking for but after fiddling with your code + my code I've managed to figure out what I needed. 

Thank you for the documentation. Loops are something that I want to improve on. I'm not one to give up on stuff. I'd spent about 4 hours trying to get the result I needed. That was at the point where I decided to ask for help. The initial array in the post took me about 100 lines of code to get to so I wasn't just wanting someone to do this for me. I'd been coding to get to this stage.

Comment: @Jack well I'm really happy that you tried something! Can I know what was your exact expected result? So I can improve the answer if possible.

Comment: @Mehdi Remembering back it was good, I was initially confused because the var dump result didn't look like the traditional array I'm used to. I used another foreach ($count as $key => $val) to loop through that array and store each of the values in my MySQL database! :D

Answer (score -1):

You should create a for loop inside of a for loop to solve this.

I can try explaining the steps as clearly as possible:

- Create an new array ($totalInstalls)
- Loop trough the array you specified
- Loop trough each element in the array you specified (for loop inside a for loop)
- Check if the campaign index of the current element already exists in $totalInstalls
- If not set it to the installs
- If it does exists increment it by one

Comment: Just saved my edit, I've added them each to an array. Although this only stored all of the values in the 27 array.

Comment: @JackEllis Try using the campaing ID as index and the total installs as value in the $totalInstalls array

Comment: how do you specify which to use as the index?

Comment: You should read the array manual of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php